# Accordion color - Wordpress Visual Composer plugin

Tags: wordpress, accordion, background-color, visual-composer

I am turning here with an issue I can't seem to solve.
For these tabs: http://helsus.org/2776-2/  I am currently using a accordion (via Wordpress Visual Composer plugin). I am not able to change each tab/its tile into a different color (which is needed for the project). Each try ends with the all the titles in the same color (for example, now it's violet).

I have associated each of the tabs/tab titles with a custom ID, but when I try to insert this ID into a code,  it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to get each of the tab into a different color?

Help would be appreciated!

Edgars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the VC editor it is not possible to give each tab a different color.

You could solve your problem with CSS. I don't think it's really that convenient.

```
#prog-vides-darzs .vc_tta-panel-heading {
    background: black;
}

#prog-veselibas-darzs .vc_tta-panel-heading {
    background: green;
}
```

You could repeat this for every item in your accordion.

It could also be possible to do this within the VC editor but this will require some customization to either the core of VC or for you to create a custom VC element.

Comment: Thank You Bas van Dijk!

It is a bit embarrassing, but yesterday I tried a similar code (I even think that within them was also the one You provided), and it didn't work.

But it does now - much appreciated.

Ye,s I now it is not the most convenient way, but it will do for now.